# jquery prices list fibonacci

Tags: javascript, jquery, fibonacci

Hi i have a javascript function that supposed to make prices and i didn't find any jquery functions that can help me out.
Here's the logic behind

```
1 user to 4 will pay = 40 / user so 3users = 120
5 users to 9 will pay = 36/ user so 7 users = 268
10 users to 19 will pay = 32/user so 15 users =  564 
20 users to 49 will pay 28/user so 40 users = 1220
50 users to 99 will pay 24/ user so 60users  = 1860
100 users to infinite will pay 20/ user so 114 users = 3000
```

I need some sort of function to do that, i've tryed to make it with multiple arrays and with function to check if number it's between 2 numbers ...

Comment: What does it have to do with fibonacci?

Comment: Seriously, why can't you write a few tests to determine the price per user and after that do a multiplication ?

Comment: Sorry i thought that fibonacci will help me on this but i was wrong, it's not how ianpgall wrote i created a similar function but my results are not right. Besides i can't do a multiplication becouse if i have 7 users the price will be 10>7>5 so the price will be 7*36=252 but the right price it's 268 becouse 40+40+40+40+36+36+36 that's the logic

Answer (score 2):

I think I understand, so something like this may work:

```
function getTotal(num_users) {
    var amount = 0;
    if (num_users >= 100) {
        amount = 20;
    } else if (num_users  >= 50) {
        amount = 24;
    } else if (num_users  >= 20) {
        amount = 28;
    } else if (num_users  >= 10) {
        amount = 32;
    } else if (num_users  >= 5) {
        amount = 36;
    } else if (num_users  >= 1) {
        amount = 40;
    }
    return num_users*amount;
}
```

Here's a jsFiddle to demonstrate:

http://jsfiddle.net/VqZ7j/1/